# How to impliment dynamic localization asp net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization

I am trying to come up with the best way to localize an asp net mvc website dynamicly. As in the administrator of the website should be able to change any string, in any language, at any time without recompiling. I was beginning to think that using SQL would be a good idea, but that would seriously take a hit at performance.

My other idea was to store localization in xml files, but then read from them as needed. However, I dont remotely know where to begin. I have seen some guides on how to do this with resource files, but those are compiled and not editable on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I've not used it personally take a look at this by Rick Strahl (A Microsoft MVP)  http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Apr/01/Updated-WestwindGlobalization-Data-Driven-Resource-Provider-for-ASPNET it may be a good fit for what you require.

It is available on NuGet here http://nuget.org/packages/Westwind.Globalization .

Also worth noting is this page covering support for MVC http://www.west-wind.com/westwindwebtoolkit/Docs/index.htm?page=_2r1166lmq.htm

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx) post may be useful for you